# How to know execution stats for mongo bulk query using spring data jpa and mongotemplate?

Tags: spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I needed to know how could i know the details of the bulk execute query either through mongo shell or through spring boot code. My code  :

```
for (Map<String,Object> record : updateRecords) {
    Update update = new Update();
    Query query = query(where("_id").is(record.get("Id")));
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : record.entrySet()) {
        update.set(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    Pair<Query,Update> queryUpdatePair = Pair.of(query,update);
        updateList.add(queryUpdatePair);
    }
    ops.updateOne(updateList);
    ops.execute();
...
```

Comment: `ops.execute()` returns [BulkWriteResult](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/BulkWriteResult/#mongodb-method-BulkWriteResult)

Comment: ya , but that tells us about rows modified and i wanted how many docs were scanned .How could I know execution stats for this query? @Valijon

Comment: well you can use mongoDB profiles to see the stats. In spring-data-mongodb you won't get statistics like you get in hibernate. But you can use profiles which will record performance for all queries/ops executed on DB and you can check them.
https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/mongodb-query-performance/